# Getting not in index error in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am calculating a new column in dataframe using the below logic

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
# BDay is business day, not birthday...
from pandas.tseries.offsets import BDay
df.StartDate_Prior = (df.StartDate - BDay(1))

df.StartDate
0    2020-11-24
1    2020-11-19
2    2020-11-09
3    2020-11-10
4    2020-11-12
```

But when I try select the datafrme Like below

```
df13[['StartDate_Prior','fyPlannedStartDate']]
```

**Error:**

"['StartDate_Prior'] not in index"

How to fix this?

Comment: What is your pandas version? Need `df['StartDate_Prior'] = (df.StartDate - BDay(1))`

Comment: @jezrael, its `1.1.2`

Comment: hmm, I think it should raise error if use `df.StartDate_Prior` for new column. Check Alexander answer in dupe.